How to enable extension loading for sqlite on ionic react app for ios?
Iam developing an app using ionic-react for ios platform. App use openlayers and caches some geospatial data from server.
I need to add spatialite extension with my sqlite local db. Sqlite extension loading is disabled by default. When I try to enable extension loading on sqlite using @capacitor-community/sqlite plugin. It returns an error extension loading is not implemented on ios. I need to integerate the spatialite extension with sqlite db. Is there any work arounds? or any other ways to make it work?
